# React: Open (.json) file via dialog and read content

Tags: html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can't seem to figure out how to load a local .json file and read the content - so I can dump it into some ´state´.

The code looks like this so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Files from 'react-files'

class LoadFile extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="files">
        <Files
          className="files-dropzone"
          onChange={file => {
            console.log(file)
          }}
          onError={err => console.log(err)}
          accepts={['.json']}
          multiple
          maxFiles={3}
          maxFileSize={10000000}
          minFileSize={0}
          clickable
        >
          Drop files here or click to upload
        </Files>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LoadFile
```

The logged object does not have any of the data buried inside of it..

```
[Object]
  0: Object
    id: "files-1"
    extension: "json"
    sizeReadable: "288B"
    preview: Object
      type: "file"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like @dkniffin said, what behind `react-files` is [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer).

You could utilize the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API to get the file content and parse it in JSON format, you could see the result in the console section of CodeSandbox below:

[image: Edit FileReader2]

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    jsonFile: {}
  };

  this.fileReader = new FileReader();

  this.fileReader.onload = (event) => {

    // or do whatever manipulation you want on JSON.parse(event.target.result) here.

    this.setState({ jsonFile: JSON.parse(event.target.result) }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.jsonFile);
    });
  };

}

...

render() {

    return (
       <div className="files">
         <Files

          ...

          onChange={file => {
              // we choose readAsText() to load our file, and onload
              // event we rigister in this.fileReader would be triggered.
              this.fileReader.readAsText(file[0]);
          }}
         >
           Drop files here or click to upload
         </Files>
       </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I actually had a try with fileReader, but I see that my semantic was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have a complete answer for you. However, after digging into the source code of `react-files` for a bit, I found [this line](https://github.com/mother/react-files/blob/master/src/index.js#L28):

```
let filesAdded = event.dataTransfer ? event.dataTransfer.files : event.target.files
```

It appears that `filesAdded` will be a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), which is basically just an array of [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to get the content from a `File` object. Maybe someone else can help out with that.